# VB.NET Create a dictionary of Sub

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I'm currently trying to create a dictionnary that looks like this :

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Action)
dict.Add(1, MySubFunction1)
dict.Add(2, MySubFunction2)


 Public Sub MySubFunction1()
    'do something, return nothing'
End Sub

Public Sub MySubFunction2()
    'do something, return nothing'
End Sub
```

Problem is, I cannot use Action with sub function like i saw in c#.
Shoud i replace "Sub" by "Function" and always return something, like this :

```
Public Function MySubFunction1()
    'do something'
    Return True
End Function

Public Function MySubFunction2()
    'do something'
    Return True
End Function
```

Or is there any better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Action` and `Sub` is the right combination.
But unlike in c# you cannot use just the method name as a delegate, you need to use `AddressOf`:

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Action)
dict.Add(1, AddressOf MySubFunction1)
dict.Add(2, AddressOf MySubFunction2)
dict(1).Invoke

Public Sub MySubFunction1()
    Console.WriteLine("Test")
End Sub

Public Sub MySubFunction2()
    
End Sub
```